# Why CNN doesn't give higher accuracy over simple MLP network? [From Keras examples]

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, keras

I'm still new to machine learning and just came across powerful deep learning library, Keras.

I've read Keras document and tried few Keras examples on Github [here](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/tree/master/examples). I've also studied some basic knowledge and concepts of deep learning from several sources but still haven't really had solid understanding in CNN and RNN which look to be very powerful networks.

So, to prove my assumption, I downloaded reuters_mlp.py example from Keras Github which originally uses simple MLP networks as a model. I combined the idea of CNN which I got from imdb_cnn.py example to reuters_mlp.py example and then observed the result.

Surprisingly, the result didn't come out like I expected. CNN performed worst than simple MLP networks. Can someone please explain why the accuracy of CNN is lower than the simple MLP networks?

Here are the outputs (Tensorflow as backend)

8982 train sequences, 2246 test sequences, 46 classes, num_words=1000

MLP (sequences_to_matrix, mode=bianry):

Epoch 1/5
8982/8982 [==============================] - 3s - loss: 1.3236 - acc: 0.6984
Epoch 2/5
8982/8982 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.7182 - acc: 0.8250
Epoch 3/5
8982/8982 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.4544 - acc: 0.8864
Epoch 4/5
8982/8982 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.3197 - acc: 0.9192
Epoch 5/5
8982/8982 [==============================] - 2s - loss: 0.2511 - acc: 0.9356
1920/2246 [========================>.....] - ETA: 0s

Test loss: 1.05213204963 Test accuracy: 0.785396260071

CNN (pad_sequences):

Epoch 1/5
8982/8982 [==============================] - 81s - loss: 1.9794 - acc: 0.5181
Epoch 2/5
8982/8982 [==============================] - 78s - loss: 1.4289 - acc: 0.6591
Epoch 3/5
8982/8982 [==============================] - 79s - loss: 1.1546 - acc: 0.7175
Epoch 4/5
8982/8982 [==============================] - 78s - loss: 0.9639 - acc: 0.7663
Epoch 5/5
8982/8982 [==============================] - 77s - loss: 0.8378 - acc: 0.7935
2240/2246 [============================>.] - ETA: 0s

Test loss: 0.960687935512, Test accuracy: 0.764470169243

Comment: Without providing your model architecture there is little others can do to help.

Comment: Why do you only train for 5 epochs?

Comment: Your test accuracy is almost the same. It looks like your MLP is overfitting a lot, since train acc is so much higher than test. You should use a validation set and follow the val_acc score

Answer (score 1):

Looking over the architectures in those two files, it seems that the [CNN](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/imdb_cnn.py) provided uses a smaller number of filters than the [MLP](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/reuters_mlp.py). Try changing the `filters` and `hidden_dims` parameters to 512, the number of neurons used in the hidden layer of the MLP.